# Crystal report viewer show text objects with top margin

Tags: crystal-reports, alignment, crystal-reports-2010

My report viewer show my text objects with extra space at top so all text objects not align well and this just only in the web viewer.
but if I try to print or see the pdf converted file it show all my text objects in right place horizontally aligned with my data.

any idea about how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Export as PDF works fine, along with in the designer; but under the CrystalReportsWebViewer it has that additional spacing.  Using CR 13.0.4.

Answer (score 3):

I found this response on another site:

This is actually a Crystal Reports bug which affects 13.0.4 Version, it works fine when you run the same report using the 13.0.3 (and probably earlier) version. This bug is known to the CR team but won't be fixed till October (3 months to fix something that worked fine previously...): http://scn.sap.com/thread/3207181

Comment: my version is 13.0.2000.0 which cause the problem !