# Crystal Report text object alignment changes at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, alignment

Im using Visual studio 2010 and crystal report 13. When I design the crystal report the alignment of the text object looks perfect. But When I execute, the text object alignment changes. Can any 1 help me to fix this issue.The output works perfectly in other systems and if I print it comes correctly. The problem is only when I view the report in my development system.

**Below is my design view:**
[image: Design View]

**And my output looks like:**
[image: Output]

Comment: I think your issue might be similar to this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872559/crystal-report-viewer-show-text-objects-with-top-margin

Comment: I resolved the problem by installing Crystal report service pack 5. Now it works perfect.